# Is there a document about translation of Salesforce features such as custom field, objects?

Tags: translation

For example, when you change user language to French, "New Custom Field" becomes "Nouveau champ personnalisé". Is there a document that I can find names all (at least some) features?

Comment: this will be set based on your user. Language and Locale information for the user will depict how things appear for the system level things. Otherwise the response below and also Translation workbench

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there exists an existing list with all the translation, you can find them easily in your salesforce org with [`Rename Object, Tab, and Field Labels`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_rename.htm&type=5).

In salesforce, it would appear as:

[image]